# Transforming pandas dataframe from multiple series to categorical label

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in set up in this way:

| depth | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 0.6 |
| 2 | 0.4 | 0.7 |
| 3 | 0.3 | 0.8 |

and I want to get it into this layout:

| depth | y | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | val1 |
| 1 | 0.6 | val2 |
| 2 | 0.4 | val1 |
| 2 | 0.7 | val2 |
| 3 | 0.3 | val1 |
| 3 | 0.8 | val2 |

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.melt` for this:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['depth'])
```

Result:

```
depth   variable    value
1       val1        0.5
2       val1        0.4
3       val1        0.3
1       val2        0.6
2       val2        0.7
3       val2        0.8
```

To get to your desired output, add `var_name` as variable, sort your values, rename 'value'-column and reorder the columns:

```
pd.melt(
        df,
        id_vars=['depth'], var_name='category'
    ).sort_values(['depth', 'category']
    ).rename({'value':'y'}, axis=1
    ).iloc[:, [0,2,1]]
```

```
depth   y       category
1       0.5     val1
1       0.6     val2
2       0.4     val1
2       0.7     val2
3       0.3     val1
3       0.8     val2
```